# Maven Compiler plugin -source is different than -target parameter

Tags: maven

I have the following in the mail pom.xml file:

```
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
```

Is it correct? Please tell me whether what are the actual usages of -source and -target tags?

Also, my requirement says "For the maven plugin, just make sure is it compiled in Java 7".

Comment: You should keep them in sync. The source mean you should keep your source code JDK 6 (which will not 100% work in that way) and are giving via `target` to compile for JDK 7 ...which makes from my point of view no sense...

Answer (score -2):

`source` and `target` parameters are propagated from maven compiler plugin to `javac` compiler from SDK.

Having source less than target is questionable. As @khmarbaise mentioned in comment, this means your source code is compiled JDK6 but you require JVM for Java 1.7.

However it makes sense to have target **lesser** than source. For example

```
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.6</target>
```

should compile JDK 8 code and produce bytecode compatible with Java 1.6+ JVMs. Although I have never tried it - behaviour may even differentiate between different Java language implementations (OpenJDK, OracleJDK,...)

Comment: Example fails on Open JDK 15.0.1 with a message "Fatal error compiling: warning: source release 1.8 requires target release 8 -> [Help 1]"